# How to update eagerly loaded entity with relations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am using EF4 with ASP.Net MVC, and I wonder how am I to update entity which was loaded eagerly?

When I load the entity as follows:

```
static readonly Func<Entities, Guid, IQueryable<Call>> CallByGuid =
        CompiledQuery.Compile<Entities, Guid, IQueryable<Call>>(
        (db, callGuid) =>
            db.Calls                    
            .Where(c => !c.Removed && c.CallGUID.Equals(callGuid)));
    public Call GetCall(Guid guid)
    {
        return CallByGuid.Invoke(_db, guid).Single();
    }
```

and pass the entity to the View, edit it there and return back to Controller and save it as follows:

```
public Call UpdateCall(Call call)
    {
        _db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(call, EntityState.Modified);
        _db.Call_VoiceCall.ApplyCurrentValues(call);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        Call dbCall = FindCall(call.CallGUID); 
        return dbCall;
    }
```

everything works fine, though quite slow. When I load the entity as follows:

```
static readonly Func<Entities, Guid, IQueryable<Call>> CallByGuid =
        CompiledQuery.Compile<Entities, Guid, IQueryable<Call>>(
        (db, callGuid) =>
            db.Calls
            .Include("Call_VoiceCall")
            .Include("Call_Rating")
            .Include("Memos")
            .Include("Company")
            .Include("PhoneService")                    
            .Where(c => !c.Removed && c.CallGUID.Equals(callGuid)));
    public Call GetCall(Guid guid)
    {
        return CallByGuid.Invoke(_db, guid).Single();
    }
```

the list of entities loads very fast, but I cannot update an entity: what I get is

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_*Call*_5599FCED3AE4474F'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Call'. The duplicate key
>   value is (6d078f37-29e6-4e56-9853-d793994ce163). The statement has
>   been terminated."

or something like this.

Now, since it is almost impossible to google questions on the similar topic, I am doing something seriously wrong. What is it?

Comment: At which line do you get this exception? I have the feeling the problem has to do with your view, especially how you bind the model to the view and what gets posted back and bound to the model again.

Comment: I am not doing anything explicit in the view and binding. The exceptions I get either in ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(...) or in SaveChanges().

It must be something architectural, methinks.